# How to convert std::vector<uchar> to NSData when using C++ file iOS project

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, nsdata, stdvector

When using C++ file for algorithm execution in iOS Project,I came across a problem where a function returns std::vector data of jpeg image.

I have been searching for this particular question of how to convert from **std::vector< uchar >** to **NSData** and convert it to **UIImage**.

But unfortunately found none with lot of trial and error I came across a solution which I am posting along with this question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To understand **std::vector< uchar >** is a byte array.

To convert it to NSData we need to use the following approach

1. Here **getFrontFaceJPEG()** is a C++ function which returns Jpeg data in the form of **std::vector< uchar >**
   `std::vector<uchar> vectorImg = img.getFrontFaceJPEG();`
2. Once it returns **std::vector< uchar >** we need to convert it to **NSData** using below method:
   `NSData * imgData = [[NSData alloc] initWithBytesNoCopy:vectorImg.data() length:vectorImg.size() freeWhenDone:false];`
3. Finally you can convert to UIImage  `UIImage *resultimage = [UIImage imageWithData:imgData];`